# Maximum size of a square in a rectangular grid filled with smaller squares

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, math

So I have a grid that can have infinite rows and infinite columns. Every time a row or a column is added I want to keep the grid same size but subdivide it into smaller squares. Every cell in the grid is same size.

If I have 5x5(cells) and have a total dimension of 500 pixels when I add a new column making it 5x6, grid should still keep the dimension of 500 pixels but scale down all the cells to allow a new column to be added as well as compensating for the x pixels of space between cells.

My question is; how do I calculate the size of the cells so they fill the dimension provided?

Known variables:

- Dimension (float) (pixels) (Variable name below: _dimension)
- Number of Cells on each row (integer) (Variable name below: Width)
- Number of Cells on each column (integer) (Variable name below: Height)
- Space between Cells (integer) (pixels) (Variable name below: GridCellSpaceInBetween)

Below code works with adding columns but doesn't work with adding rows since I only consider Width. Or is it impossible to keep the same dimension at all?

```
    float cellSizeBeforeSpaceRemoved = _dimension / Width;
    float cellSizeAfterSpaceRemoved = cellSizeBeforeSpaceRemoved - GridCellSpaceInBetween;
    
    for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            int index = x + y * Width;

            cells[index].rect.position = new Vector2(x * cellSizeBeforeSpaceRemoved, y * cellSizeBeforeSpaceRemoved);
            cells[index].rect.size = new Vector2(cellSizeAfterSpaceRemoved, cellSizeAfterSpaceRemoved);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The size of an individual cell is a float but the space between cells is an integer?  That's weird to me.

Comment: If you want the cells to remain squares, you need to compute `dimension / width` and `dimension / height` and choose the smaller of those as the `squareSize`. Then you need to compute the horizontal and vertical space between cells.

Comment: If you have rectangle, you should provide both vertical and horizontal dimensions. Also it is not clear how are you going to distribute shrinking between cells and spaces